# Raid 6 mdadm creation error

Tags: raid, mdadm

I am trying to create a 4 drive raid 6 with mdadm in Ubuntu. The command I am using is

```
sudo mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=6 --raid-devices=4 /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd /dev/sde
```

the error I am receiving in return is

```
mdadm: An option must be given to set the mode before a second device (/dev/md0) is listed
```

I really couldn't find much that helped me when searching google, I found one thing that suggested it had something to do with the automated email. I thought that was unnecessary so I tried to skip. Is there a way I can go back now and set that up if that's causing problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that a RAID is not already running by issuing the following command:

`cat /proc/mdstat`

if you see something like this:

```
Personalities : [raid1]
md0 : active raid1 sdb1[1] sda1[0]
104320 blocks [2/2] [UU]

md1 : active raid1 sdb3[1] sda3[0]
19542976 blocks [2/2] [UU]

md2 : active raid1 sdb4[1] sda4[0]
223504192 blocks [2/2] [UU]
```

issue the following command to stop the RAID:

`sudo mdadm --stop /dev/md0`

you might have to remove the existing array:

`sudo mdadm --remove /dev/md0`

then try building the array again:

`sudo mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=6 --raid-devices=4 /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd /dev/sde`

Hope this helps.

Comment: cat /proc/mdstat returns "Personalities: unused devices: <none>" is that what I should be seeing if it's not working?

Comment: Well, it was my own foolish fault. I didn't realize I needed to format the drives prior to creating the raid. After doing so everything seemed to work out fine. I'm going to accept your answer as the information is correct.

Comment: @CharlieS Glad you fixed it.  Also glad you figured out you needed to format your drives.   I'm going to take note of that for future as well.  Have a great weekend!